# Rails Nested Attributes trying to update a record id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I have a problem with nested_attributes, I have the next entities:

```
class Experience < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles, inverse_of: :experience
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :experience, inverse_of: :roles
end
```

I have the next set of parameters:

```
 params = {"end_date"=>"02/01/2012",
 "city"=>"Buenos Aires",
 "state"=>"",
 "country"=>"",
 "title"=>nil,
 "company"=>"Restorando",
 "current"=>nil,
 "description"=>nil,
 "roles_attributes"=>
  [{"id"=>558, "title"=>"System Owner", "start_date"=>"03/01/2000", "end_date"=>"02/01/2001", "description"=>"<p>I did a bunch of stuff</p>", "current"=>false},
   {"id"=>561, "title"=>"Test", "description"=>nil, "current"=>nil},
   {"id"=>557, "title"=>"Full Stack Developerr", "start_date"=>"01/01/2011", "end_date"=>"02/01/2012", "description"=>"<p>Full Stack Developer description</p>", "current"=>false}],
 "resumes_experiences_attributes"=>[{"id"=>384, "resume_id"=>809}, {"id"=>385, "resume_id"=>3199}]}
```

And I want to update a rails model. So I execute:

```
@experience = Experience.find(some_id)
@experience.update_attributes(params)
```

This returns me an error

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate
>   key value violates unique constraint "roles_pkey"

If I see what Rails is trying to update I see the next `sql` statement:

> UPDATE "roles" SET "start_date" = $1, "end_date" = $2, "current" = $3,
>   "id" = $4, "description" = $5, "title" = $6, "created_at" = $7,
>   "updated_at" = $8 WHERE "roles"."id" = $9  [["start_date", nil],
>   ["end_date", nil], ["current", nil], ["id", 561], ["description",
>   nil], ["title", "Test"], ["created_at", "2017-06-23 10:54:10.194605"],
>   ["updated_at", "2017-06-23 10:54:10.194605"], ["id", 558]]

Which to me is strange because it's trying to update a record `id`, if you see the statement you will see: `"id" = $4` and the where clause `WHERE "roles"."id" = $9` which is correct, but its taking two different `id` values.

Instead if I execute:

```
@experience = Experience.include(:roles).find(some_id)
@experience.update_attributes(params)
```

It works perfectly

The initial case also works if I enter a rails console and manually trigger it. I don't know why this is happening, of course there are more complexity in the applications and I just give you the basic data to solve it but any insight would be helpful.